# jQuery - changing page with sending a POST parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

scenario is:

I have HTML a-tag in a page(call it 'index.php') which is a link to another page (lets call it page 'action.php') !  obviously

'action.php' page needs to receive a POST parameter, otherwise it return error!

i have the needed parameter in 'index.php' page, but i dont want to use form-tag to send it. Whenever user clicked on the a-tag, the parameter should be sent to the 'action.php' page. 

Indeed, AJAX has nothing to do here, while i want to change the page, with sending the POST parameter whenever user click on my < a > !


example:
index.php

```
<a class='showProject' href='action.php' data-pid='<?php echo project_ID ?>'> PROJECT </a>
```

action.php

```
 echo $_POST['project_id'];
```

i prefer that, if there is any way to do this, the jQuery Code starts with the following event:

```
$('.showProject').on('click',this,function(e){

     /* YOUR SOLUTION */
});
```

Comment: Have you ever read about Ajax?

Comment: i want to change the page with sending POST parameter, when user click on <a> instead of <button type='submit'> of a <form> !!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ajax for this. I don't know where you have the parameter you want to pass to action.php, but in my example it's stored in a hidden value.

```
$('.showProject').click(function() {
  var productId = $("#hiddenField").Value();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'action.php',
      data: {productId: productId},
      success: function(data) { 
              //Do whatever you need to do with the return data.
          },
      error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownerror) { }
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class='showProject' data-action-url='action.php' data-pid='<?php echo project_ID ?>'> PROJECT </span>
```

If you want to use Ajax don't use `<a>` Tag. instead use a span or button.

If you use `<a>` tag, set `href='#'` or `href="javascript:void(0)"`

```
<a class='showProject' href='#' data-action-url='action.php' data-pid='<?php echo project_ID ?>'> PROJECT </a>
```

OR

```
<a class='showProject' href='javascript:void(0)' data-action-url='action.php' data-pid='<?php echo project_ID ?>'> PROJECT </a>
```

Then use Ajax

```
$('.showProject').on('click',this,function(e){

    $.ajax({
           method: 'POST',
           data: { project_id: $(this).data('pid')},
           url: $(this).data('action-url'),
           success: function(data){

           // HERE Assign Returned page to DIV

           } 
     });
});
```

**EDIT:**
I have never worked in PHP. But what you are trying to do doesn't seem right.

Create a new file.

controller.php

Instead of going direct to `action.php`, POST to the `controller.php`.

```
$('.showProject').on('click',this,function(e){

    $.ajax({
           method: 'POST',
           data: { project_id: $(this).data('pid')},
           url: 'controller.php',
           success: function(data){

           // Redirect to Page:
             window.location.href = URL RETURN FROM PHP;

           } 
     });
});
```

Store the id in the session.

```
// this syntax maybe wrong

$_SESSION["prod_id"] = $_POST['project_id'];

return URL // I don't know how to do that in PHP
```

In `action.php`, get the ID

```
echo $_SESSION["prod_id"];
```

Comment: thanks for your solution, but i want to change the page to 'action.php' with the POST parameter included , whenever user clicked on < a >, not just assign the result contents to a div in the same page (index.php)

Comment: something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call

Comment: why are you using POST to load a page?